Navigating http/s links without full path/dir
This might be a stupid question but how do you go back to the previous directory with https links?
For instance, I am at
https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3
But I want to go back to dir1 and into a different path like this
https://example.com/dir1/dir4/dir5
And I don't want to have to put the entire link, so that if someone clicks it from another page, it won't go to the right place but it would be able to navigate on the same page.
For those who are familiar with file paths, I want to do the equivalent of this if I'm not mistaken..
../../dir4/dir5
To clear things up:  yes, I am talking about links in an HTML web page shown in a browser.

Are you talking about links in a HTML web page shown in a web browser? Because outside of this context your question doesn't make much sense to me.
